# NodeJS: createServer fails with Connect module

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I ran:

```
install npm connect
```

Then I ran the file: test.js

```
var connect=require("connect");
var app=connect.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.end("Hello");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

But it failed with the error message:

```
Type error: connect.createServer is not a function
```

Please help !

Comment: Did you mean `http.createServer(app)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createServer`  is not part of `connect` module.It is part `http` module.You should include it.

**Connect is an extensible HTTP server framework for node using "plugins" known as middleware**

```
var http = require('http');
```

then use connect module to create app.

```
var app = connect();
app.use('/foo', function fooMiddleware(req, res) {

});
```

then create `http` server using this way.

```
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `connect()` function which is the main function of **connect** module.

```
const app = connect.createServer();
```

is the same as

```
const app = connect();
```

So for your example, you could just use

```
var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect();
app.use(function(req,res){
    res.end("Hello");
});
app.listen(3000);
```